# Bottom Tabs are hidden

Tags: android

I want to design 4 tabs bottom at the screen, but my problem is tabs are hidden at bottom of the screen.But in an empty activity the tabs are shown. see the images.
[this image is showing tabs with and without activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2lOQ.jpg)

[here is my code, xml and java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9hSM.png)

Comment: It's always hidden? Is it getting visible again when you scroll up/down?

Comment: Please describe your problem with complete details!

Comment: yes agree with @PareshMayani

Answer (score 0):

Try setting property
`android:layout_above="@id/tabs"` to FrameLayout

**Edit:**

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```